# spritekit sidescroller how to move hero through the level

Tags: ios, spritekit, swift

I am trying to learn spritekit by working my way through developing a simple side scrolling game, but I cannot find a clear answer on how to move the hero through the level.

The width of my ground far exceeds the width of the view and I have always thought it was best to move the ground not the hero, but my enemies (who pace back and forth) tend to move much more quickly as the hero moves and to the wrong spot. I am guessing this is because the ground is moving and changing their destination during the move action.

Is moving the ground (not the hero) the best way to create a sidescroller without a repeating landscape. If so, how do I create enemies that move in a restricted area like mario?

Here is a portion of my code:

```
let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyWalk1.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemyWalk1.png"), size: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    enemy.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    enemy.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

    enemy.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + enemy.size.width + 800, y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + ground!.frame.size.height + enemy.size.height)
    self.addChild(enemy)

    var enemyGoTo1 = enemy.position.x + 100
    var enemyGoTo2 = enemy.position.x - 100

    var enemyXScale1 = SKAction.scaleXBy(1, y: 1, duration: 0.0)
    var enemyXScale2 = SKAction.scaleXBy(-1, y: 1, duration: 0.0)

 enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(enemyTextureArray, timePerFrame: 0.15)), withKey: "enemyWalk")
    enemy.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([enemyXScale1, SKAction.moveToX(enemy.position.x + 100,duration: 1.5), enemyXScale2, SKAction.moveToX(enemy.position.x - 100,duration: 1.5), enemyXScale1, enemyXScale2])))


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if nodeAtPoint(location) == rightArrow {
                rightTouched = true

            }
        }     
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        if rightTouched == true {
            childNodeWithName("ground")!.position.x = childNodeWithName("ground")!.position.x - 8
        }   
}
```

Comment: I suggest to delete(and move it to another question) the last part(asking about how to make enemies) because the first question is big enough itself so you may get a better answer, also please elaborate your question more with codes and pictures.

Comment: so you want to have fixed landscape, and it should stay there or move very slow? as a parallax?

Comment: I did move it to the game developer site, but did not get a response. I would like the character to move throughout the level by pressing back or forward, so the user determines where he goes. I don't know if I should move the ground or move the character and somehow the view with him.

Comment: You shouldn’t move the character toward your scrolling axis, just background should be moved and the landscape should be moved slowly to create a paralax effect, I will post you a refrence to learn from it, this kind of game are known as endless runners.

Comment: So, move the ground and keep the character stationary?

Comment: yes you may keep it stationary but games like mario lets their character to move slightly toward the scrolling direction but just a little, However it doing this at the start would increase the complexity, I suggest to add such a effect after finishing the game prototype version.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! This should get me started. The biggest struggle for me now, is having the enemy move to a location with a duration. If the ground is moving during too, the enemy appears to move very fast, because the ground is moving as well. I hope the tutorial addresses this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29196/discussion-between-iman-and-user4812000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define some classes first

- Background
- Enemy
- Player (your hero)
- Life Bonus (for example or power up or ….)
- GameScene,ViewController,appDelegate

and you should define some essential method on them like generating a background for your game on class Background something like this (from the below book)

```
+ (ERGBackground *)generateNewBackground
{
    ERGBackground *background = [[ERGBackground alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"background.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.name = backgroundName;
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.zPosition = 5;
    background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 34) toPoint:CGPointMake(background.size.width, 34)];
    background.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCollisionBitmask;
    SKNode *topCollider = [SKNode node];
    topCollider.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    topCollider.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBodybodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, background.size.height - 30) toPoint:CGPointMake(background.size.width, background.size.height - 30)];
    topCollider.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
    [background addChild:topCollider];
    return background;
}
```

In background moving you need to create just two set of background in a moment and switch the first to the secound, one when it reaches to the end.

Paralax should also be created in background class

```
(ERGBackground *)generateNewParallax
{
    ERGBackground *background = [[ERGBackground alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"parallax.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.name = parallaxName;
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.zPosition = 4;
    return background;
}
```

Unfortunately the codes are in objective C you have to change them to swift which I that would be very easy.

Please read the following book which is totaly about how to create an endless runner game. It also has some example that you can download and start to change it to have your own.
as I see, you hav’t started to code yet, so I think this is a good start for you :

[Read This Book](http://www.leoffdd.fr/fichiersprojets/salamanderlille-iOS%207%20Game%20Development.pdf.pdf)

> I read this book, it is really a good one and will push you into endless runner games.